# undefined method error for :string

Tags: ruby

I have this code...

```
foo = opt_source.downcase.camelize
"#{foo}".new.start_check
```

this should call a class and the method start_check, but I am getting an undefined method error

> undefined method `start_check' for "Abcd":String (Abcd is the class that foo represents)

Any suggestions on how what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what's the value of `opt_source`? I need to know on which you called `new`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert that string into a constant. Historically this was done with `eval` but this leads to security issues in your code -- never `eval` user-supplied strings.

The correct way to do this (in Rails) is via [String#constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize):

```
foo = opt_source.downcase.camelize
foo.constantize.new.start_check
```

For ruby, use [Kernel#const_get](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_get):

```
foo = opt_source.downcase.camelize
Kernel.const_get(foo).new.start_check
```

Don't forget to check for errors before calling your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just `eval(foo).new.start_check`

Answer (score 0):

Create a class name from a plural table name like Rails does for table names to models.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify

camelize is not fit to convert plural string into active record class if you are calling method from active record

For example:

```
u = "batteries"
u.camelize #=> "Batteries"
u.classify #=> ""Battery"
```

Try

```
opt_source.classify.constantize.new.send(:start_check)
```